# How to convert BizTalk policies to make it readable

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-rule-engine

I have received a XML file containing the BizTalk policies for a BizTalk-application. Of course the XML file is fairly difficult to read (unless you are a BizTalk developer of course).

Now, I have to present the rules to my client, and I need to convert these rules into something human readable, e.g. an Excel spreadsheet. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean with biztalk policies? Do you mean policies for the business rule engine? Or are you talking about the binding file?

Comment: Even BizTalk developers have trouble reading the XML files.  Usually the first thing we do with that is import the vocab and policy into BizTalk and use the Business Rules composer to actually look at the policy and vocab.  As boatseller has suggested, BizTalk Documenter can document those rules into a help file.  However there are currently a few bugs in it (including Business Rule documentation) some of which I've posted fixes for http://biztalk2010autodc.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Answer (score 3):

There are two options you can try, both available at CodePlex:

BizTalk Documenter: http://biztalk2010autodc.codeplex.com/

ShoBiz: http://shobiz.codeplex.com/